How to change external screen brightness using powershell?
I have a second external display and am trying to set the display brightness using powershell.
I can easily set the brightness for the Primary (built-in) display, using the following:
# Get CIM object for Primary Display
$m = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods

# List Primary display's properties
$m | select *

# Set brightness and timeout of primary display object
Invoke-CimMethod $m -MethodName WmiSetBrightness -Arguments @{Brightness = 80; Timeout = 1}

However, I can see the same type of object using WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods, which shows both my displays.
# List ALL displays by InstanceName
Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods

# See details of each
$k = Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods
$k | select *

But I am not able to use the 2nd display instance (given by InstanceName).
How can I change the brightness of the 2nd display instance?

You can call the SetMonitorBrightness Function

@SantiagoSquarzon Ok, so how do you use that? Can you post an example? The link does have anything useful for PowerShell.

You can Add-Type the class from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61417175/15339544 and use it to set all monitors brightness

Using inline C# seem a bit too hackish. Sure would probably work, but I'm looking for a pure and more clean posh (!) solution. I don't understand why you can change brightness in 1-2 lines of primary display, but can't do the same for a 2nd...

You can't use the $k instance of the 2nd monitor, maybe $k[1]?

@js2010 Well, IDK how to do it, as it is listed under a different class name. Basically I expect it to be possible to specify the display InstanceName in the 1st example (using $m) but sine it is not listed there, I have no idea how to go about it.

Oh the class is different.  The first class doesn't show both monitors?

@js2010 Exactly.
